# How to make software that does not require anyone to download anything

Tags: java, networking

So, the title I used may have been questionable, anyways, essentially what I want is for people to be able to use my software without needing to download it.

Here is an example: there are connection types like RAW & TELNET, is it possible for me to make a program that uses one of these protocols so if my users want to use the software they can directly connect using PuTTY or something by entering my server address and port.

I am sorry if this does not make sense, I am hoping someone knows what I am talking about as its very hard to explain....

EDIT: I just found this - [Telnet Client Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57077136/telnet-client-program), kind of what I am looking for, sadly he got no responses.

Comment: You can serve interactive command-line programs over SSH and telnet. What have you tried?

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "software that does not require anyone to download anything". Does it include downloading your software (I know it is strange question but still, maybe that is also what you meant...)? For now your question looks like unclear [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: And what about a web-based application? This question is really vague.

Comment: @Pshemo So here is a example, when you create a commandline application you can use it over ssh / cmd, essentially what I want is to prevent any and all users from having any kind of access to the .jar, I just want them to be able to use the program via something like telnet, this is probably very undescriptive but here is a peice of code i found that may be useful i guess (in c) - https://hastebin.com/esayanorux.cs, i think this is using the RAW connection type.

Answer (score 0):

So, almost any computer now already has browsers. Just use vanilla JS and HTML if you want to get rid of dependencies.

I'm pretty sure for TELNET and SSH prococols, you'll need the user to ask to download something like PuTTY under Windows, or some package dependency under Linux/Android, and then you're forcing dependencies (download PuTTY or else). If you want that way, anyhow, you can build a character-based application with NCURSES or just a command-line based application.